# paint a wall where the surface is uneven

Tags: walls, kitchens, painting

I have remove most of the wallpaper in my kitchen, to be able to paint it.

However, the surface is uneven and I'm not sure what kind of products I can use to make the wall smoother and to apply painting on it.

[image]

A friend of mine suggested to sand down the wall.

What do you think of that suggestion?

If this is not the right suggestion, what else can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skimcoat with drywall compound. The suitability of that may depend on your skills with a trowel.

You can add a layer of 1/4" drywall on top, or you can remove the wall surface (do any maintenance that makes sense while it's open) and replace with new drywall.

Comment: Hi @Ecnerwal, is there any ready to use solution? I'd be honest, I'm not that skilled with a trowel... and my wish is do something like this lady --> https://www.uglyducklinghouse.com/coat-of-many-layers-skim-coating/

Comment: Joint compound is about as ready to use as you can get when you buy it in a bucket. There is no magic solution - you either have to do work, or hire someone else to do work, or live with a lumpy wall.

Comment: @Ecnewal fair enough , I will do the work. No way to live with it.

Comment: Don't underestimate the need for skill/practice at skimming out a wall. If it was me (and I'm a working carpenter that has been forced to sling drywall mud over a great number of years), I'd find a pro. If you DIY, try hard to get low dust (aka 'dust control') drywall compound.